Are these cassettes suitable for expressing PETase mutant in E. coli?
I created two potential gene expression cassettes (constitutive and inducible) for expression of a mutant PETase gene on PeptiCloud using the version tree feature, which allows users to create multiple versions for a biological sequence and organize it in a single location. Could you please check if the cassettes (nodes 3 and 5 in screenshot) are suitable for expression in E. coli K12? The original paper and plasmid sequence are attached in the files section. My project can be found in this link: https://www.pepticloud.com/public-project/PETase 
